# Issue - Delegate click event jQuery 1.4.2 (IE8)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I used jQuery 1.4.2 and had a problem with delegate click event for radio button on IE8. I had to click twice to trigger click event on radio element.

HTML:

```
<div id="data"></div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#data').delegate(':radio', 'click', function () {
        alert(1);
    });

    jQuery("#data").append('<input type="radio" value="abc" name="flight_group"/> abc');

    jQuery("#data").append('<input type="radio" value="de" name="flight_group"/> de');

});
```

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/secretlm/n4G9Z/3/

Thanks so much.

Comment: Try with `change` event.

Comment: What does the `:` do in `input:[name=flight_group]` selector? Did you try `input[name=flight_group]`

Comment: @php-dev: I tried to use change() event and remove ':'. However, it still not working on IE8

Comment: @secretlm I can't open your JSFiddle page, the page load again and again with no result, is it normal?... I can see other Fiddles...

Comment: @secretlm No change, I cant' access it. Try maybe to make another fiddle link by clicking "save"

Comment: @secretlm The link is OK now. I tested your code with my IE8 browser and a JQuery 1.4.2 and everything is good. Pay attention that the codes in your fiddle and in your post are differents now. (why?) Try to clean the cache, it may cause lots of problems...